# How to use indices returned from 'min' function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, indexing, min

How can I use the indices returned from 'min' function in matlab to retrieve its data in a 3D matrix on third dimension?
for example, I have the code below:

```
%a is a 3D matrix
[res, index] = min(a, [], 3);
```

An I want to access the min elements using index, something like:

```
a(index);
```

NOTE: I want not to use res variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get them all:

```
a=rand(3,2,3);
[res, index] = min(a, [], 3);

sizeA=size(a);
sizeA12 = prod(sizeA(1:2));
lin_idx = sub2ind([sizeA12 sizeA(3)],1:sizeA12,index(:)');
a(lin_idx)

ans =

        0.0344   0.0971   0.171   0.695  0.0318  0.187

>> res(:)'

ans =

        0.0344   0.0971   0.171   0.695  0.0318  0.187
```

### More general approach

```
a=rand(3,2,3); % sample data

dim_min = 2; % dimension along to take the minimum
[res, index] = min(a, [], dim_min);

sizeA       = size(a);
sizeAstart  = prod(sizeA(1:dim_min-1));
sizeAend    = prod(sizeA(dim_min+1:end));
idstart     = repmat(1:sizeAstart,1,sizeAend);
idend       = repmat(1:sizeAend  ,1,sizeAstart);

lin_idx = sub2ind([sizeAstart sizeA(dim_min) sizeAend ],idstart,index(:)',idend);
a(lin_idx)
```

You can also reshape the result to get it in the same dimensions as the original matrix (with omission of the minimized dimension):

```
reshape(a(lin_idx),sizeA([1:dim_min-1 dim_min+1:end]))
```

Works for any size of data matrix or any value `dim_min` (as long as `1<=dim_min<=ndims(a)` of course)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly I haven't got the required reputation points to comment Gunther's (almost six years old) answer, but there is an error here, which makes the "More general approach" incorrect:

The "idend"-index should not be duplicated with repmat, but with repelem instead, to get the required 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 order for this index. So here's a functional example of Gunther's approach:

## More general approach (corrected idend)

```
a=rand(3,2,3); % sample data

dim_min = 2; % dimension along to take the minimum
[res, index] = min(a, [], dim_min);

sizeA       = size(a);
sizeAstart  = prod(sizeA(1:dim_min-1));
sizeAend    = prod(sizeA(dim_min+1:end));
idstart     = repmat(1:sizeAstart,1,sizeAend);
idend       = repelem(1:sizeAend  ,1,sizeAstart);

lin_idx = sub2ind([sizeAstart sizeA(dim_min) sizeAend ],idstart,index(:)',idend);
% check correct result
isequal(a(lin_idx)',res(:))
```